# Wrong date formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I'm using Morris.js to display a line chart, and feeding it with timestamps as X axis values.
As an example will be better than any explanation, here is an example data :

```
{   
"1415376000":
    {"VALUE1":0,"VALUE2":0,"VALUE3":16,"VALUE4":0},
"1415980800":
    {"VALUE1":0,"VALUE2":0,"VALUE3":2,"VALUE4":0},
"1416585600":
    {"VALUE1":0,"VALUE2":0,"VALUE3":2,"VALUE4":0},
"1417190400":
    {"VALUE1":0,"VALUE2":0,"VALUE3":7,"VALUE4":0},
"1417795200":
    {"VALUE1":10,"VALUE2":6,"VALUE3":16,"VALUE4":3},
"1418400000":
    {"VALUE1":5,"VALUE2":4,"VALUE3":67,"VALUE4":5},
"1419004800":
    {"VALUE1":3,"VALUE2":0,"VALUE3":38,"VALUE4":3},
"1419609600":
    {"VALUE1":4,"VALUE2":1,"VALUE3":24,"VALUE4":1}
}
```

As you can see, "1419609600"-ish data are Unix Timestamps (created via the php [mktime() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)). The time between two timestamps is dynamically generated, here, it's one week (604800 seconds).

After a simple Morris.Line() initialization, here is the  result : [image: result]

The date is strangely formatted, and poorly transformed : actual dates generated with mktime() are from November-December 2014...

After adding `dateFormat: function (x) { return new Date(x * 1000).toString(); }` (instead of the default `dateFormat: function (x) { return new Date(x).toString(); }`) parameter at initialization, transforming this seconds timestamp into to a milliseconds timestamp, the result is closer than what we expect :

[image: result2]

But then, how to display this date as a "05-12 Dec 2014" for example ? I tried to play with the `xLabels` parameter, `dateFormat` parameter, but this either does not change anything or throws errors.

As a side question, since my timestamp have a dynamical range (the difference between the timestamp min and timestamp max can be one day, one month, one year...), is there a way for Morris.js to take this into account and dynamically adapt to this range, displaying either days, or monthes, ... ?
From my understanding of the documentation, this should be possible, but I can be wrong...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dateFormat: function (x) { 
var d = new Date(x * 1000);
var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
return d.getDate()+' '+monthNames[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getFullYear();
}
```

Try it,

> about javascript methods
>
> `getDate()` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp
>
> `getMonth()` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp
>
> `getFullYear()` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp